# SQLite Room Database: Receiving data from specific Column and Row not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-room, dao

I have a SQLite Room Database with 5 columns(Day, Likes, Dislikes, plays, Blocked). I have populated the database manually with 8 rows of data in the Database.

From the database I want to retrieve a specific data for a specific day. So I need number of likes (or Dislikes, plays,...) for day 6 (or 1,2,3,4...)

I tried to create the necessary `Dao`, `Repository`, and `ViewModel` methods, but they seems wrong  because when I call it in `MainActivity` it gives me 0 as the return value.

Database Sample:

```
@Database(entities = Recovery.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class RecoveryDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static RecoveryDatabase INSTANCE;
public abstract RecoveryDao recoveryDao();

// Singleton
public static RecoveryDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (RecoveryDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), RecoveryDatabase.class, "recovery_database").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().allowMainThreadQueries().addCallback(roomCallback).build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

private static RecoveryDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        new PopulateDbAsyncTask(INSTANCE).execute();
    }
};

private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private RecoveryDao recoveryDao;

    private PopulateDbAsyncTask(RecoveryDatabase db) {
        recoveryDao = db.recoveryDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        recoveryDao.insert(new Recovery(1,22,9,2,3));
        recoveryDao.insert(new Recovery(2,23,8,3,4));
        recoveryDao.insert(new Recovery(3,56,6,4,5));
        recoveryDao.insert(new Recovery(4,34,4,2,2));
        recoveryDao.insert(new Recovery(5,76,2,7,9));
        recoveryDao.insert(new Recovery(6,10,1,4,7));
        recoveryDao.insert(new Recovery(7,27,6,7,3));
        recoveryDao.insert(new Recovery(8,46,7,1,5));
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next options:

1. Set column name `likes` explicitly in your DAO (it's not clear for Room what column you want use for value to return):

```
@Query("SELECT likes FROM recovery_table WHERE day=:day")
int getRecoveryWithDay(int day);
```

2. Change type of value your DAO return to `Recovery` (it is better choice if you want to get several values - likes, dislikes, plays with one query):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM recovery_table WHERE day=:day")
Recovery getRecoveryWithDay(int day);
```

You then can get `likes` in your Activity:

```
int day = RecoveryDatabase.getInstance(this).recoveryDao().getRecoveryWithDay(6).likes;
```

If neither of options work check if there is really row in your database with day = 6 with some sqlite browser

Comment: Hey Thank you for your help. I have done both of your suggestions and they are both throwing me the "Cannot create an instance of class ... RecoveryViewModel.. I think I am doing something wrong in the repository and viewmodelclass. I have updated the questions with the updated changes. I have also commented on where I made the changes so it's easier for you to see. Could you please tell me the changes I must make. Thank you again. I am understanding more.

Comment: I have made a minor change to the viewmodel and I am getting = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.example.Recovery.getLikes()' on a null object reference
Do you know what I must do to fix?

Comment: `NullPointerException` means that `RecoveryDatabase.getInstance(this).recoveryDao().getRecoveryWithDay(6)` is null (that means row with day = 6 was not found). So you better check with sqlite browser whether needed data with day = 6 really exists. Try to localise your can-find-row-problem first without calling intermediate ViewModel's and Repository's methods, since at least in Repository you are using different variables - `mDatabase` and `database`.

Comment: ok, I see what I am doing wrong. In the RecoveryRepository constructor, I have created the RecoveryDatabase database using the "application" context. so the variable now has the database access and I've connected that with Dao. With this information I have created a variable above the constructor as private Recovery mRecoveryWithDay. And added this inside the constructor " mRecoveryWithDay = database.recoveryDao().getRecoveryWithDay()". But when I do this I need to send in the requested day. I do not know what to do now. Help? And The database that I've posted above in question is prepopulated

Comment: ok, I looked into a bit more and in the getRecoveryWithDay method, I am returning "recoveryDao.getRecoveryWithDay(day)" and I have nothing thats related to this on the constructor. For me this seems all right. But I am still getting the same error. I have updated the question with my full Database class, which I used to populate the database manually. And are there any SQLite browsers that you recommend, I am new to SQLite. Thanks for all the help my friend!!!, Thank you.

Comment: As for SQLite browsers for Android Studio - [here](https://medium.com/@mattyskala/browse-sqlite-database-in-android-studio-4fbba6cca105) one of them (it's a plug-in). On new Android Studio 4.1 there is [built-in database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#database-inspector)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help once again. I have tested everything and it works as intended and I understand it way better now.